# how to get the primary key value - SubSonic

Tags: subsonic

how to get the primary key value after the tablename.Save() method

For Example:

```
Table.Save();
```

here how to my auto generated primary key value...

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways. You can just check the primary key property, so if you Table has an auto incrementing integer primary key you could do:

```
int primaryKeyValue = Table.Id;
```

Or you could use the KeyValue() method, which returns an object:

```
object primaryKeyValue = Table.KeyValue();
```